# Normal link redirects to friendly URL

Tags: get, seo, clean-url

Is it possible in any way to treat

`<a href="product.php?cat=mobile&sub=android&page=xy">link1</a>`

as

`prodcuct/mobile/android/xy` in address bar. I mean when click on the `'link1'`  will show the SEO friendly url in address bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your title doesn't represent your real question.

Comment: @Rafael Barros  so what the title should be?I can edit

Comment: Something like: "Normal link redirects to friendly URL".

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible because your product create the extension from a PHP database and if list it as "prodcuct/mobile/android/xy" Google Bot find crawl error page does not found in your google webmaster tool.

So my suggestion is write php code that when ever new product page is created using your backend; make product name to create automatically as page name. Then your site can links can be index really fast.